# deploying renamed page layout and record types in Prod from FULL

Tags: deployment, administration, page-layout, record-type, change-set

I have recently refreshed my FULL sandbox with Prod. I wish to rename some page Layout and record type name( Label and API name) in FULL. I have added some section to this renamed page layouts and added some new pick list field to record types in FULL.

Now I would like to use the change set to move these renamed page layouts and record type to Prod using Change set. I believe it would create new page layouts and record type when I deploy the change set to prod. I would have to delete the existing page layouts and record type in prod.

What is the best way to do this? Should I rename the page layouts/record types in Prod, so when I deploy the change set from FULL , it would just override the existing page layout/record types in Prod?